# Why does Microsoft warn from using PerRequestLifetimeManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unity-container

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.perrequestlifetimemanager(v=pandp.30).aspx states that:

> Although the PerRequestLifetimeManager lifetime manager works correctly and can help in working with **stateful** or thread-unsafe dependencies within the scope of an HTTP request, it is generally not a good idea to use it when it can be avoided, as it can often lead to bad practices or hard to find bugs in the end-user's application code when used incorrectly. It is recommended that the dependencies you register are stateless and if there is a need to share common state between several objects during the lifetime of an HTTP request, then you can have a stateless service that explicitly stores and retrieves this state using the Items collection of the Current object.

What kind of bugs or bad practices is the warning refering to? How would one use it incorrectly? - Unfortunately the warning is not very specific and is therefore hard to apply to the real world. Furthermore it is not clear to me what stateful means in this context.

IMHO a typical scenario to use the PerRequestLifetimeManager would be some kind of database connection (e.g. DbContext) or similiar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its purpose would be to only instantiate one instance per request, which could (for example) prevent redundant operations and lookups during the course of a single request.

The danger is if someone assumes that the object created is a good place to store state during the request. The idea of dependency injection is that a class receives a dependency (commonly an interface) and doesn't "know" anything about it at all except that it implements that interface.

But someone could reason that if the object is going to persist throughout the life of the request then it's a good place to maintain state during the request. So they create a complex scenario where one class receives the dependency, stores some information in it (like setting a property), and then another class receives that same dependency and expects to read that property.

Now the purpose of dependency injection (decoupling) has been defeated because classes have built-in assumptions about what the lifetime of that dependency is, and may even include assumptions about what other classes have done or will do with the state of that object. That creates a tangled mess where the interaction between classes is difficult to perceive - even hidden - and so it's easy to break.

Let's say someone determines that the lifestyle of that dependency should be transient, not per web request. Suddenly all of the behaviors of those classes that depend on it stop working as expected. So developers look at those classes and see that nothing has changed. What happened? The interaction between those classes was hard to see in the first place, so when it breaks the problem will be hard to find. And if there was some valid reason why the lifestyle of that dependency was changed then the problem is going to be even harder to fix.

If we need to store state during a request then we should put it in "normal" places like in the `HttpContext`. There's still room there for some confusing practices and bugs, but at least we know that the `HttpContext` is (by definition) going to be tied to a particular request.