# Instanciate Entity Framework context per request via Microsoft Unity in WebApi 2.0

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

I have a N-layer solution that works correctly in my dev environment. Apparently it works also on production environment, but sometime the execution fails. I do not understand why. I just know that nothing changes on database, no usefull error is visible and no log is written. 
My supposition is a concurrency problem. I think that something fails when I try to do more than one select once the entity framework context has been initialized.

Here how my solution is structured

[image]

In the facade I inject the entity framework context. Here the configuration on my web.config of the service interface:

```
<containers>
  <container>
    <types>
      <register type="it.MC.IContext.IDataContext, IContext"
                mapTo="it.MC.EntityFrameworkContext.PublicAreaContext, EntityFrameworkContext">
        <lifetime type="singleton" />        
      </register>

      <register type="it.MC.IFacade.IPublicAreaFacade, IFacade"
                mapTo="it.MC.Facade.PublicAreaFacade, Facade">
        <interceptor type="TransparentProxyInterceptor" />
        <lifetime type="singleton" />
        <constructor>
          <param name="context" type="it.MC.IContext.IDataContext, IContext"/>
        </constructor>
      </register>
    </types>
  </container>
</containers>
```

As you can see, my context and the facade are singleton. I think both are really wrong. I think that both Facade that the entity Framewrk context should be instanciate per request. I think this will solve the problem of the concurrency too.

Can anyone help me to correct my code please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that your question is:

> Can anyone help me to correct my code please?

I read it like this:

> Can anyone help me change this code so that `IContext` and `IFacade` will be re-initialized per request.

With that said... Yes, I also doubt that you want to keep your `IContext` as a singleton.

[Why you shouldn't use singleton DataContexts in Entity Framework](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/03/dont-use-singleton-datacontexts-entity.html)

Here's how you can change the lifetimemanager to [`PerRequestLifetimeManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.perrequestlifetimemanager(v=pandp.30).aspx), if that's what you want. Note that you probably need the [Unity.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/) NuGet-package.

```
<containers>
  <container>
    <types>
      <register type="it.MC.IContext.IDataContext, IContext"
                mapTo="it.MC.EntityFrameworkContext.PublicAreaContext, EntityFrameworkContext">
        <lifetime type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.PerRequestLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc" />        
      </register>

      <register type="it.MC.IFacade.IPublicAreaFacade, IFacade"
                mapTo="it.MC.Facade.PublicAreaFacade, Facade">
        <interceptor type="TransparentProxyInterceptor" />
        <lifetime type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.PerRequestLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc" />
        <constructor>
          <param name="context" type="it.MC.IContext.IDataContext, IContext"/>
        </constructor>
      </register>
    </types>
  </container>
</containers>
```

Before moving to production I suggest you read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439331/why-does-microsoft-warn-from-using-perrequestlifetimemanager) about the `PerRequestLifetimeManager`.

> Its purpose would be to only instantiate one instance per request,
>   which could (for example) prevent redundant operations and lookups
>   during the course of a single request.
>
> The danger is if someone assumes that the object created is a good
>   place to store state during the request. The idea of dependency
>   injection is that a class receives a dependency (commonly an
>   interface) and doesn't "know" anything about it at all except that it
>   implements that interface.

Also, think about the `Facade` you got, and how it will work if it's re-initated every request. Does it perform any heavy operations at initialization? You might want to think about the lifetimemanager for that one.

**UPDATE**
Since you're using WebAPI you should be able to use `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` instead.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

> The dependency resolver attached to the HttpConfiguration object has
>   global scope. When Web API creates a controller, it calls BeginScope.
>   This method returns an IDependencyScope that represents a child scope.
>
> Web API then calls GetService on the child scope to create the
>   controller. When request is complete, Web API calls Dispose on the
>   child scope. Use the Dispose method to dispose of the controller’s
>   dependencies.

http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/introducing-the-unity.webapi-nuget-package

> If you are registering any components that implement IDisposable such
>   as Entity Framework's DbContext, you will want to make sure that these
>   components get disposed of at the end of the request. This is achieved
>   by registering these components with a HierarchicalLifetimeManager.

Comment: Interesting.. I had seen that perRequestLifetimeManager but I was not sure was the correct solution because I need the unity.mvc package and I do not have mvc.

Comment: I do not think the facade is a problem, because all the initializations inside it are lazy. The PerRequestLifrtimeManager should not be a problem because my back end is stateless. I just have a doubt. In the link you sent me is written: Let's say someone determines that the lifestyle of that dependency should be transient, not per web request. What transient means?

Comment: Transient means that it's newed up every time. Not per request or singleton, but everytime it's resolved. I'll try to find a resource for WebApi as well.

Comment: So in my case, transient should coincide with the request because I risolve the context in the facade that is called once per request

Comment: @Ciccio - Yes, in that case Transient is correct. You can also try with `PerResolveLifetimeManager`, which creates an instance per resolve-cycle. Set a debugger in your dispose and constructor (or log it). Then make a few requests and you should see it beeing created and disposed.